# Modify regular expression to allow negative numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I found this script that was a perfect solution for me, a few lines of code instead of having to install another plugin to format numbers.

```
$(document).on('keyup', "#importo", function (event) {

// skip for arrow keys
if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

// format number
$(this).val(function (index, value) {
    return value
        .replace(/\D/g, '')
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".")
        ;
   });
});
```

Now I have the problem i need the script to allow also negative numbers. How could i change it?

Comment: You can add this ^\-?[1-9]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
 return value
    .replace(/(?!^-)[^0-9]/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".")
    ;
```

In the first replace it replaces everything but digits and hyphen in the beginning of a word. I don't know if that will do in your case.

Comment: This allows hyphens in the middle of the number.

Comment: Oh, you're right, i edited it, now it should work as wanted.

Comment: inputValue.replace(/(?!^-)[^0-9]/g, ""); this one works perfectly. can you tell me how can We allow negative numbers as well as decimal number?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the most straightforward change that I can think of since Javascript regular expressions don't support lookbehinds.

```
$(this).val(function (index, value) {
    if (value.length === 1) {
        value = value.replace(/\D/, '');
    } else if (value.length > 1) {
        value = value[0].replace(/[^-\d]/, '') + value.slice(1).replace(/\D/g, '');
    }

    return value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more to what you are looking for. I wrote a regex that only allows numbers/digits but is also allows negative numbers. It uses the JS match method on the value. The return is an array so you have to get your result from the zero index.

```
$(document).on('keyup', "#importo", function (event) {

// skip for arrow keys
if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

// format number
$(this).val(function (index, value) {
    var digits = value.match(/(^-\d*)|(\d*)/g); // allows digits starting with - or just digits only. 
    return digits[0];
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex should handle negative sign `-` also. Please try:

```
$(this).val(function (index, value) {
    if (value.length === 1) {
        value = value.replace(/\D/, '');
    } else if (value.length > 1) {
        value = value[0].replace(/[^-\d]/, '') + value.slice(1).replace(/\D/g, '');
    }

    return value.replace(/\B(?=((?:-)?(?:\d{3})+)(?!\d))/g, ".");
```

});